# Kafka sql, structure with key as dot notation

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

[image]

I am having some trouble when trying to access the key with dot notation inside a struct.
[image]

When I do that, It gives this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
[image]
After looking up the JSON structure with "PRINT <topic_name> FROM BEGINNING,
I just had to create the structure according to the object in the key "value:".

I got confused with the data type that was generated with apache avro and forgot  that I changed it to JSON, this way it modified the structure.

Comment: You should mark you own answer as "accepted".